# Keeping off Bluetooth/WiFi during application runtime

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-wifi

We can turn on/off WiFi/Bluetooth programmatically.
 But is it possible that as long as the application is running that has
 turned off WiFi/Bluetooth they would remain off. 
I mean to say that if User turn WiFi on then application will again turn that to off?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an intent filter and register a receiver when your application is started

```
<intent-filter>  
<action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/> 
<action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"/>  
</intent-filter>
```

register receiver on onCreate

```
IntentFilter filters = new IntentFilter();
filters.addAction("android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED");
filters.addAction("android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE");
super.registerReceiver(wifiStateListener, filters);
```

although in your case I think only "android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" will suffice. Whenever the state of WIFI (enable, disable, connect, disconnect) is changed it is fired by os.

You need to add the permission to read/modify WIFI state.

Hope this helps.